# Compatibility issue of pygame and OsmGpsMap

Tags: python, pygame, gtk, openstreetmap, osmgpsmap

I am writing a program on Python 3.4 that uses GTK Map widget (OsmGpsMap) and pygame for joystick input. 
Here is a simple program that displays a window with a map:

```
import gi
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import OsmGpsMap

window = Gtk.Window(Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL)   
window.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
map_widget = OsmGpsMap.Map()       
window.add(map_widget)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

But if I just add a

```
import pygame
```

line (without pygame.init() and etc.), the program doesnt launch and I receive a message that python.exe have stopped.

So, how is it possible to fix that?

Comment: As a crossplatform library I don't think PyGame applications could show a osmgpsmap which is a Gtk+ widget.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix frameworks. The frameworks may interact poorly with each other or conflict completely. If it works on your (operating) system, that doesn't mean it will work on another (operating) system or with a different version of one of the frameworks. Mixing frameworks always means some kind of undefined behavior.
Pygame is based on SDL2, so there is no chance that PyGame can display an osmgpsmap which is a Gtk+ widget.